# Returning min and max based on sum of column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `Employees` with the columns: `day`, `employeeid`, `earned`, `hourofday`. So I have different rows such as:

```
day        | employeeid | earned | hourofday
25/01/2019 | 422        | 50     | 14
25/01/2019 | 422        | 60     | 15
25/01/2019 | 422        | 40     | 16
```

**I want to find out which employee has the minimum and maximum TOTAL EARNED per day?**

So far I have managed to return the summed up earned / hours:
`SELECT day, employeeid, SUM(earned_that_hour) as earned_that_day FROM Employees GROUP BY day, employeeid`

Then I've attempted to use MAX() and MIN() on the `earned_that_day` column:

```
SELECT day, campaignid, MAX(earned_that_day), MIN(earned_that_day) 
FROM (SELECT day, employeeid, SUM(earned_that_hour) as earned_that_day FROM Employees GROUP BY day, employeeid) 
GROUP BY day, employeeid
```

But both MAX and MIN columns return the sum, instead of minimum and maximum values for each day&employeeid. How do I modify the query to return? I have 4 current days

Comment: Where is the python relevance?

Comment: I guess there is none, but I am using sqlite, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 CTEs, to get the sum for each employee per day and the max/min per day.
Then join them:

```
WITH 
  cte AS (
    SELECT day, employeeid, SUM(earned_that_hour) as earned_that_day 
    FROM Employees 
    GROUP BY day, employeeid
  ),
  maxmin AS (
    SELECT day, MIN(earned_that_day) minearned, MAX(earned_that_day) maxearned
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY day
  ) 
SELECT c.*
FROM cte c inner join maxmin m
ON m.day = c.day AND (c.earned_that_day IN (m.minearned, m.maxearned))
ORDER BY c.day, c.earned_that_day
```

Comment: This returns a partial correct result. I have data that spans 4 different days. and the first 3 days it does return 2 rows for each day, namely employeeid with most earned that day and employeeid with least earned that day, but for the last day it returns 10 rows: the max earned that day and the employee id, and then 9 different rows with employees that earned 0

Comment: If there are more than 1 employees with the minimum what do you want returned?

Comment: On second thought, this result is good! I know they are all equal on earned=0. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT day, employeeid, SUM(earned_that_hour) as earned_that_day,
             MIN(SUM(earned_that_hour)) OVER (PARTITION BY DAY) as day_min,
             MAX(SUM(earned_that_hour)) OVER (PARTITION BY DAY) as day_max
      FROM Employees e
      GROUP BY day, employeeid
     ) e
WHERE earned_that_day IN (day_min, day_max)
ORDER BY day;
```

Comment: I am getting `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: e`

Comment: Are you aliasing your employees table?